# Traversing focus on right and left arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, focus, accessibility

First press the tab key, the first link will be highlighted then press the right arrow keys to see the focus jumping to next level navigation traversing ahead, similar way once I click the left arrow key focus has to come back.

In the following code keycode 39 is working fine. Can someone help me once i press keycode 37 the focus has to go back.

[Full html code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hamedali/w3y2mhcn/1/).

```
<script>
$('.we-mega-menu-ul>.dropdown-menu a').keydown(function (e) {
if ([37, 39].indexOf(e.keyCode) === -1) {
    return;
}
var link = $(this);
switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37: // left arrow key
    // Make sure to stop event bubbling
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (link.parent('li').find('li').filter(':visible').first().length === 0) {
        link.parent('li').find('li').filter(':visible').last().find('a').first().focus();
    }
    else {
        link.parent('li').find('li').filter(':visible').first().find('a').first().focus();
    }
    break;
    case 39: // right arrow key
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (link.parent('li').find('li').filter(':visible').first().length === 0) {
        link.parent('li').find('li').filter(':visible').last().find('a').first().focus();
    }
    else {
        link.parent('li').find('li').filter(':visible').first().find('a').first().focus();
    }
    break;
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please post the corresponding HTML code, so that the structure is made clear? This will certainly help answering your question.

Comment: Is that code an example, or is the final solution organised vertically, as well? Is there a reason you used horizontal arrow keys in a vertical list?

Comment: After resolving the issue with the arrow keys, it would be recommended also to have the TAB key exit the list, instead of jumping to the next item. (:

Comment: Your code is giving me the impression that there are some misunderstandings. link will not be the top level element, but the current element, as you bound to each <a>’s keydown event. Then, your `if` conditions for left and right are exactly the same and seem too complicated. Wouldn’t `link.parent('li').find('li')` simply return `link` itself?

Comment: Please note that e.keyCode is deprecated, and using magic numbers like 37 or 39 is not a good coding practice. It is recommended to [use e.key instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key), which works with more speaking names like “ArrowLeft”.

Comment: Hi @QuentinC, the complete HTMl is in below fiddle. Thanks in advance
https://jsfiddle.net/hamedali/w3y2mhcn/1/

Comment: Hi @Andy, yes this is the requirements we got from our Accessibility team.